# Swift SpriteKit Contact check inside the PhysicsBody

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I am working on PhysicsBody and get some troubles.
First I don't really now if this is with PhysicsBody possible or only with pixel check.

The problem is: Contact check works pretty well but if a node is inside a PhysicsBody it won't be able to see if it collides.
in the Pictures it is pretty well explained.

[Picture 1: This works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxCMP.png)

[Picture 2: This won't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlTkf.png)

Some ideas how it works?
Maybe PhysicsBody(Green Line) fill with the SKNode?

Here some Code:
(Some explain: if Human moves inside Object and Touched is false nothing happened and it is okay but if Human is moved inside Object and Touched will be True nothing happened too and this is my problem.)

```
    enum myContacts: UInt32 {
    case None   = 0
    case All    = 0xFFFFFFFF
    case Object  = 0b001
    case Human = 0b010
}

class whatever...{
    let Object = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "xyz")
    Object.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frame), CGRectGetMidY(frame))

    Object.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: Object.size.width/2)
    Object.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    Object.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = myContacts. Object.rawValue
    Object.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = myContacts.Human.rawValue
    Object.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    Object.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    addChild(Object)

    let Human = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "zyx")
    Human.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frame), CGRectGetMidY(frame))

    Human.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: Human.size.width/2)
    Human.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    Human.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = myContacts. Human.rawValue
    Human.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = myContacts.Object.rawValue
    Human.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    Human.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    addChild(Human)
}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if touched {
        let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
        switch contactMask {
        case myContacts.Object.rawValue | myContacts.Human.rawValue:
            print("Human touched")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    touched = true
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    touched = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I completely understand what you are asking, but if you just want to detect a contact when node is spawned inside the space "taken" by another node, this code will work:

```
#import "GameScene.h"

static const uint32_t playerCategory     =  0x1 << 0;
static const uint32_t obstacleCategory   =  0x1 << 1;

@interface GameScene()<SKPhysicsContactDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) SKSpriteNode *player;

@property (nonatomic, strong) SKSpriteNode *obstacle;

@end

@implementation GameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

    [self initializeNodes];


}


-(void)initializeNodes{


    self.player =  [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor greenColor] size:CGSizeMake(50,50)];

    self.player.name = @"player";

    self.player.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    self.player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.player.size];
    self.player.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
    self.player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCategory;
    self.player.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    self.player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = obstacleCategory;

    self.player.zPosition = 10;

    [self addChild:self.player];


    self.obstacle =  [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor yellowColor] size:CGSizeMake(100,100)];

    self.obstacle.name = @"obstacle";

    self.obstacle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    self.obstacle.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.obstacle.size];
    self.obstacle.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0;
    self.obstacle.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = obstacleCategory;
    self.obstacle.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
    self.obstacle.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory;

    self.obstacle.zPosition = 8;

    [self addChild:self.obstacle];

}





-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact{
    NSLog(@"Contact detected!");
}


-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}

@end
```

Here, everything is pretty much straight forward:

- I make two nodes and assign physics bodies to them
- I place those two nodes at the same position
- As a result, a contact is detected

If you copy & paste this code and run it, what you are going to see in the console is the message which says : "Contact detected".

I guess that is the same situation from the second picture (where you are saying that contact is not detected).

Also, if you continue to move the player (while a player is inside of an obstacle's bounds), the further contacts will not be detected. Player have to leave the bounds of an obstacle first. But still, you can check the return value of [allContactBodies](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPhysicsBody/allContactedBodies) method which returns an array of SKPhysicsBody objects that current body (player's physics body) is in contact with.

Comment: My issue is that it don't show me the contact if it don't touch the green lines anymore, so if a value gets true to check contacts it won't work cause it checks the contact only if it happened new. allContactedBodies is a nice idea but maybe slow if I have 500 fast moving objects?

Edit: Maybe easier with Node.intersectsNode(AnotherNode)?

Comment: @Lirf Yeah, allContactBodies in that case is probably not a performant solution. intersectsNode: could work, but you should update your question with a code which can reproduce what you are saying. That way you will probably get a better answer.

Comment: @Lirf Not much to say... What you are experiencing is perfectly normal in SpriteKit and that is how physics engine works. didBeginContact is triggered only when contact between two bodies is made. So, even if you set your variable to true, that will not trigger didBeginContact at the moment when you are expecting it (a contact is probably already made before that). You should try with if node.intersectsNode if you think you will experience a performance issues with looping through array of bodies returned by allContactBodies() method.

Comment: is there a way to add more Physic points in a Node?
for example more green lines inside the Object?